# NameServers not updating

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, godaddy

I have a domain on Godaddy, in the morning I have updated the nameservers to point to Linode Servers, after about one hour, everything was ok.

Now, when after sometime, when i'm trying a dig on the domain name, it is again pointing to Godaddy Servers though i've changed it to linode servers, also in the Godaddy DNS Manager, i'm seeing that the nameservers are that of linode,

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
tripmauritius.com.  3558    IN  SOA ns65.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net. 2014092901 28800 7200 604800 3600
```

My question is why the domain still pointing to godaddy nameservers although I have changed it to linode servers?

Comment: You've made a statement. Do you have a question?

Comment: question added, :)

Comment: The domain is delegated to the linode nameservers. i just checked. you're probably seeing cached records.

Comment: the issue is that i'm not being able to use the domain name

Comment: NS record updates can often take 48 hours, that is two days due to long TTL values.

Comment: Why aren't you able to use the domain name? You just need to make update the old servers in parallel until the caches clear.